# Input field focus state in react not working with the given style

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, algorithm, styled-components

I have an input field in my react project to display a separate component when it's in a hover state. I have a separate component called [Focus Style] from the Actual component but all I'm doing is not working. The focus state should work with the first input field Kindly assist me. My code below.

Main Componenet

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
 import stays from "./Components/stays.json";
// import styled, {css} from "styled-components";
import FocusStyle from "../src/Components/FocusStyle";

export default function SearchGuest() {
  const [guest, setGuest] = useState("");
  const [location, setLocation] = useState("");
  const [Data, setData] = useState([]);
  const [filteredData, setFilteredData] = useState(Data);
  const [focus, setFocus] = useState("false");

  const onFocusChange = () => {
    setFocus("true");
    console.log("focused");
  };

  

  useEffect(() => {
    setData(stays);
    setFilteredData(stays);
  }, []);

  const handleSearch = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <form action="" >
        <input
          onFocus={onFocusChange}
          type="text"
          name="guest"
          id=""
          // value={guest}
          placeholder="text"
          onChange={handleSearch}
          style={focus ? { border: "1px solid yellow" } :  <FocusStyle/>  }
        />
        <input
          type="number"
          name="location"
          id=""
          // value={location}
          placeholder="number"
          onChange={handleSearch}
        />
        <button value="submit" >Search</button>
      </form>

      {console.log(filteredData)}
    </div>
  );
}
```

FocusStyle Component

```
import React from 'react'

export default function FocusStyle() {
  return (
    <div>
      <h2 style={{marginTop: "90px", color: 'pink'}}>Focus Componenet</h2>

      <div className="modal">
      <div className="adult">
    <span>Adult</span>
    <button>-</button><span>0</span><button>+</button>
    </div>

      <div className="children">
       <span>Children</span>
      <button>-</button><span>0</span><button>+</button>
      </div>


      </div>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: if focus is true you need to display <FocusStyle/> else <input /> this is what you're looking for ?

Comment: Yes @pageNotfoUnd

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if so then you can do this

```
{focus ? <input
      onFocus={onFocusChange}
      type="text"
      name="guest"
      id=""
      // value={guest}
      placeholder="text"
      onChange={handleSearch}
      style={{ border: "1px solid yellow" }}
    />: 
   <FocusStyle/>
}
```